# Disabling Smart Address Bar in Safari 5

Tags: safari

How can I disable the Smart Address Bar feature of Safari 5?

Answer (score 2):

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=932707

I guess you will have to wait for someone to write an extension for that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this extension:

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2010/08/25/smrt